# How to make spotify url prompt to open the Spotify app, not open the web-app?

Tags: spotify

I'm making my own smart link page:

```
https://www.hooklust.com/oo.a/
```

(only part way through - ignore the horrible styling)

and can get the Spotify link (top green button) to open the song in the Spotify web app, but how is a service like this...

```
https://songwhip.com/hooklust/sekai-heiwa-world-peace
```

able to prompt to open the Spotify app after the Spotify link is clicked please? When I click theirs, I see the "Open Spotify - https://songwhip.com wants to open this application." prompt.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to open the link directly in the app is to use the URI instead of the URL, e.g. in your case link to *spotify:track:2bmgv7q8RgC0NgF9SlGlpe* instead of https://open.spotify.com/track/2bmgv7q8RgC0NgF9SlGlpe:

```html
<a href="spotify:track:2bmgv7q8RgC0NgF9SlGlpe" target="_blank">
```